# Can't use variable outside of the function. Gives undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, this

I have this npm packages that shortens url and it doesn't have much document. It takes this "this.src" url and shortens it. I want to use the "url" element in html how do I do this? It gives me undefined.

```
<template>
  <div id="image">
    <h2>Upload Successful</h2>
    <a target="_blank" :href="src">Image Link</a>
    <button @click="shorter">Short URL</button>
    <p>{{ urlShare }}DD</p> //GIVES UNDEFINED

    <div class="img">
      <a target="_blank" :href="src"> <img :src="src" alt="" /> </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
var shortUrl = require("node-url-shortener");

export default {
  name: "Image",
  props: ["src"],
  data() {
    return {
      urlShare: null, //GIVES UNDEFINED
    };
  },

  methods: {
    shorter() {
      this.urlShare = shortUrl.short(this.src, function (err, url) {
        return url;
      });
      console.log(this.urlShare); //GIVES UNDEFINED
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: what does this.src give you?  are you sure your getting the right format?

Comment: hey thanks for the answer, it gives me an url i checked, i use the url on "    <a target="_blank" :href="src">Image Link</a>
" normally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with that package but it looks like it's using a callback rather than returning a value.  Try this:

```js
shorter() {
   shortUrl.short(this.src, (err, url) => {
      this.urlShare = url;
      console.log(this.urlShare);
   });
},
```

Comment: I will be damned. I thought I tried that it worked thanks a lot! Why didn't it work and why did this work?

Comment: You're welcome.  You probably used `function()` instead of an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).  When you use `function`, you lose access to the component's `this`, because non-arrow functions create their own `this`.